# In linux, calling system() from a forked process with pipe()

Tags: linux, fork, pipe

I have a standard program using fork() and pipe() with the intention of making a system() call for a third party program in the child process and redirecting the output to the parent process. I discovered that if I do this, somehow the parent process is never able to detect that the child process has closed the pipe, thus it is never able to exit from the while loop calling read().

The issue disappears when I replace the system() call to the third party program with some other generic system call like system("ls -l"). What could be potential issues with the call to the third party program using system() that is affecting this program?

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <fstream>
#include <stdlib.h>//system
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv){

  //setup pipe
  int pipeid_L1[2];
  pipe(pipeid_L1);

  pid_t pid_L1;
  pid_L1 = fork(); 
  if( pid_L1==-1 ){
    throw std::logic_error("Fork L1 failed");
  }
  else if(pid_L1 ==0){//L1 child process
    dup2(pipeid_L1[1],STDOUT_FILENO);//redirect standard out to pipe
    close(pipeid_L1[0]); //child doesn't read
    system( ... some program ... ); //making the system call to a third party program
    close(pipeid_L1[1]); 
    exit(0);
  }
  else{ 

    //setup pipe  
    close(pipeid_L1[1]);      

    int buf_size=64;
    char L1_buf[buf_size];

    while( read(pipeid_L1[0],L1_buf,buf_size)){ //this while loop never exits if I make the system call to the third party program
      ... do stuff here ...
    }


  }
  exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the parent will only see the EOF when ALL other processes close the write end of the pipe.  There are three relevant processes -- the child you forked, the shell that system forks and execs, and the actual program you run.  The first two won't close their end of the pipe until after the program actually exits, so the parent won't see the EOF until that happens and all the processes exit.

If you want the parent to see the EOF as soon as the program closes its stdout, rather than waiting until it exits, you'll need to get rid of those extra processes by using `exec` rather than `system`.

Alternately, you can use `popen` which does all of the needed fork/pipe/exec for you.